# WPF. Access binding collection at runtime

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I have a wpf window with some controls binded to different collections.

```
<controls:CustomTextBox ItemsSource="{Binding Countries}" />
<controls:CustomTextBox ItemsSource="{Binding Localities}" />
```

The "ItemsSource" is a Custom DependencyProperty for link with the Collection.
I want to get the collection at runtime in PreviewLostKeyboardFocus for validate if the text exists in the collection.

```
PreviewLostKeyboardFocus(object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
{
    CustomTextBox textBox = (CustomTextBox)sender;
    var bindingExpression = textBox.GetBindingExpression(textBox.ItemsSourceDependencyProperty);
    ...
}
```

I get the bindingExpression, but I don't know how to seek the text in the Collection.
Thanks.

Comment: are you trying to do something like auto-completion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you simply access the CLR wrapper for the dependency property?

```
CustomTextBox textBox = (CustomTextBox)sender;
var collection = textBox.ItemsSource;
```

For you to be able to "seek the text" in the collection, you may have to cast it to an appropriate type such as for example an `IEnumerable<string>` or whatever type `Countries` or `Localities` is;

```
var collection = textBox.ItemsSource as IEnumerable<string>;
if (collection != null)
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: Hello. Thanks for answering. If I use var collection = textbox.ItemsSource, I get a null value. The type I use for ItemsSource (Dependency Property) is List<dynamic> because the items can be of multiple type. For example: countries (Id, Iso, Name) or Localities (Id, Name, CountryId) or also Customers (Id, Code, Name, ...). I make a custom textbox class that have other properties, like field to search (Id, Iso...). I use them in xaml. The best way, I think, to get this collection that I have found is to use binding expression. With BindingExpression, I get the properties of the binding.

Comment: If the `ItemsSource` property returns `null`, your dependency property hasn't been set. Trying to retrieve the value from a binding expression makes no difference.

Comment: I found the problem. I have change the type of dependency property to IEnumerable and now if I use var collection = textbox.ItemsSource, I get the values. Thanks. And sorry for my english.